# When are assignment bonuses calculated in Atelier Escha & Logy?

Tags: atelier-escha-and-logy

In Atelier Escha & Logy, I get an assignment grid of twenty-five assignments to complete within a term.  If I complete a line of three assignments in the inner 3x3 grid, I can earn bonuses like additional points, stats, or reference books.

However, I'm not sure when this bonus is calculated.  Is this done when I submit the main assignment or when I submit the "final report" during the report phase?  Can I submit the main assignment and then work on the side assignments and turn them in later for a cumulative bonus?  Or do I need to hold off on reporting until I'm ready to grab a one-time term bonus?

Some of these bonuses look pretty powerful, and I don't want to accidentally lock myself out of them and have to backtrack a whole bunch of hours.  The wording in the help/manual is unclear on this point.

Also, are the bonuses cumulative?  If I complete two lines, would I earn both the one line and two line bonus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment bonuses are given at the time of turn in.  You don't need to worry about turning some in early; you still have the rest of the assignment period to hand in the others.  One of my habits was to get the alchemy and town ones out of the way first, hand them in, get the bonus from whatever I could, and then venture out of town to complete the rest.

The only time you want to be careful is within ten days of the due date; you can at that point proceed with the story, and carry over the remaining days into your next assignment.

One small spoiler: Your next-to-last assignment is...somewhat impossible, but don't worry.  You'll get another after that that unlocks *all* the assignments, allowing you to complete and turn in any you may have missed previously.

As for the bonuses, they are *all* cumulative.  If you complete all nine core assignments before turning them in, you'll get every bonus for that time period all at once.  But you can also get them just by turning in assignments as you complete them; completing all nine gets you all the bonuses, whether you turn them in one at a time, or all at once.